# JS is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I found this code snippets on the website bellow and the css and html work just fine but the js is not working at all no matter where i write the code. I've tried it inline, internal and external but it does not work. I've also tried different browsers like firefox, opera and I use phpstorm as my IDE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="probe.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<title>Probe!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="holder">

        <div class="bar">
            <p style="float:left"> Hello world</p>
            <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a>
        </div>
        <div class="bar2">
            <p style="float:left"> Hello world</p>
            <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a>
        </div>


    </div>


    <a href="#" class="add">+ Add 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="add2">+ Add 2</a>
    <script src="probe.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js-file (`probe.js`)

```
$( ".holder" ).sortable();
$( ".holder" ).disableSelection();
var c1 = c2 = 0;
$('.add').click(function() {
   $(".bar:last")
   .after('<div class="bar"><p style="float:left"> Hello world ' + c1 + '</p> <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a></div>');
   c1++;
});

$('.add2').click(function() {
     $(".bar2:last")
     .after('<div class="bar2"><p style="float:left"> Hello world ' + c2 + '</p> <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a></div>');
     c2++;
});

$('.delete').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

css-file:

```
.bar{
     background:#ccc;
     width:400px;
     height:30px;
     margin-bottom:2px;
}

.bar a, .bar p{
     display:block;
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
}

.bar2{
     background:red;
     width:400px;
     height:30px;
     margin-bottom:2px;
}

.bar2 a, .bar2 p{
     display:block;
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
}
```

On this website: https://jsfiddle.net/jnLfh/17

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Have you downloaded `jquery-ui.js` to your server?

Comment: in your fiddle you've not included the code that adds in the `.sortable` to the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using jQuery 1.10.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.4. I would advise using a more modern version.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xmaktcy4/9/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".holder").sortable();
  $(".holder").disableSelection();

  var c1 = c2 = 0;

  $('.add').click(function() {
    var item = '<div class="bar"><p style="float:left"> Hello world ' + c1 + '</p> <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a></div>';
    if ($(".bar").length) {
      $(".bar:last").after(item);
    } else {
      $(".holder").append(item);
    }
    c1++;
  });

  $('.add2').click(function() {
    var item = '<div class="bar2"><p style="float:left"> Hello world ' + c2 + '</p> <a href="#" style="float:right" class="delete"> remove </a></div>';
    if ($(".bar2").length) {
      $(".bar2:last").after(item);
    } else {
      $(".holder").append(item);
    }
    c2++;
  });

  $('.holder').on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't use the the old versions but I took your code and it still does not work. I also changed `.add2').click(function()` to `('.add').on("click",function()`. It does work on jsfiddle but not with my xampp apache. Do you have another idea? I think I will try it with another IDE and tell you if it worked.

Comment: I've tried to run it with visual studio code on chromium but it still does not work. So it can't be a problem with the IDE or the browser. I'm sure it has to be something with my jQuery itself.

Comment: Ok, found the problem. I added jQuery first and then JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery code needs to wait until the DOM is ready before executing. It doesn't appear that you're doing that.

jQuery Docs [document.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: `<script src="probe.js"></script>` appears at the end of the document. Waiting for the ready event won't help.

Comment: This is technically incorrect.  Aside from Quentin's point, if the script being included (for some reason) did not reference any of the elements in the DOM, it would not need to wait for it to be ready.  Construed example, if a website had an endpoint to let it grab visitor information, that endpoint could be called before the DOM was fully loaded.

Comment: @Taplar Agree. But the OP IS referencing DOM elements that may or may not exist when the code is executed.